# Why my div's doesn't expand with zoom

Tags: css, html, zooming

Hi I'm making a web page, but I notice that when I make zoom in the page with any web browser the div's doesn't expand only the text. How can make that both the div's and text expand with I make zoom in them?

This is how I'm working in css, I'm making the positioning in the same way for all my page.

```
#pagina_principal{
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
    width:90%;
    height:190%;
    border:solid red 1px;

}

#menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:5%;
    width:90%;
    height:3%;

}

#home_principal{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    width:18%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid lightgrey 1px;
}
```

Comment: You have `%` sized widths which means that div will be `90%` of the screen no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with fluid elements whose width and height are assigned in percentage. That means the browser renderer will calculate the elements' size based on the browser's window size. For instance, a 100% width element will automatically be rendered as covering the whole width of the browser's window.

The problem is, when zooming, the size of the window does NOT change, so these elements keep the same size.

Comment: ok, thanks I prove and this work perfectly, but now I have a doubt I can define the screen resolution in the body? for example body{width:2000px; height:2000px;}.

Comment: You could do that, but you will get horizontal and vertical scrollbars when your page is viewed in a window less than 2000x2000px sized.

Comment: And in a meta tag can I set the resolution of the screen?, I ask this things because I want that my design support other resolutions like mobiles resolution for example or what can I do in this case?

Comment: This is not a good solution. You should definitely read about responsive design and its techniques. There is a decent first article here : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will read the article for understand how this work.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you setting sizes in % and size of your container doesn't change when zooming. Try using pixels (px) for sizing or put everything in some container (eg. div) and set its size with pixels.